# Magento - Getting 'getLastRealOrderId' once order has been placed

Tags: magento

Once an order is placed in my magento store I have a custom module so that i can save the order number into an external database table.

My custom module setup is:

**Custom/ExternalOms/config.xml**

So i hook into the `sales_order_place_after` event

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_ExternalOms>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Custom_ExternalOms>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <custom_externaloms>
                <class>Custom_ExternalOms_ExternalOms</class>
            </custom_externaloms>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <custom_externaloms>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Custom_ExternalOms_Model_ExternalOms</class>
                        <method>exportToOMS</method>
                    </custom_externaloms>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
       </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Custom/ExternalOms/Model/ExternalOms.php**

and run my function:

```
class Custom_ExternalOms_Model_ExternalOms extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function exportToOMS()
    {
        $_order_number = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();

        // remaining code..
    }
}
```

The code runs once the order has been placed correctly but this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
```

Is coming up empty

Comment: Are you looking for the entity_id or increment_id?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Replace your event by this code 
        <events>
                    <sales_order_place_after>
                        <observers>
                            <custom_externaloms>
                                <type>model</type>
                                <class>externaloms/externalOms</class>
                                <method>exportToOMS</method>
                            </custom_externaloms>
                        </observers>
                    </sales_order_place_after>
               </events>


        ExternalOms file by this

            class Custom_Externaloms_Model_ExternalOms {
            public function exportToOMS($observer)
                {
                   $observer->getOrder();

                    // remaining code..
                }

            }
     /*     in case $observer->getOrder(); will not work than use 
                  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId(); for getting last order id and load order
            */
    I hope it will work
```